# Как вызвать исключение в запросе sql? postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть запрос на селект. К примеру `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 3 AND number > 5;`
Как мне сделать так, что если ни одна запись c id 3 не была найдена, выкинуть исключение или каким то другим образом оповестить клиента, что записи с таким id не существует?

Answer (score 0):

Запрос может вернуть 0 строк результата - это нормальное, штатное поведение запроса. Не надо это менять.

Это задача прикладного кода (того, который этот запрос и выполнял) - проверить сколько данных получено и корректно следовать необходимой логике. "запрос не нашёл данных" - это может быть индикатор неверного выполнения *приложения* и, в том числе, вызывать исключение на приложении. Но для СУБД это штатная ситуация. Обрабатывать это должно именно приложение.

Comment: Проблема в том, что приложение должно обрабатывать 2 вида логики, связанных с этим запросом. Если нет записей с number > 3 это нормально, если запись с id 3 отсутствует в системе - это проблема. Я пытаюсь решить ее не прибегая к доп запросу на проверку.

Comment: @DenverToha Я боюсь запрос слишком усложнять придется. из where проверку number точно придется убрать, что бы увидеть все записи с id=3, потом надо будет сделать так, что бы запрос всегда вернул хотя бы одну запись, что бы к ней прицепить информацию о наличии/отсутствии id=3. Ввиду этого считаю, что проще выполнить 2 запроса. Тем более второй понадобится только если первый ничего не вернул

Answer (score 0):

Я согласен с коллегой что в методах и функциях возвращающих данные не нужны исключения при отсутствии данных по указанному ключу это тупиковый путь во всех отношениях. Единственный путь программной генерации ошибок на стороне сервера это метод [RAISE](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/plpgsql-errors-and-messages). Генерировать исключения в этих случаях лучше в среднем уровне бизнес логики но и здесь лучше возвращать пустые списки чем исключения. Если все таки критически важно знать о наличии данных по указанному ключу то я использую запросы типа check,  с использованием команды [EXISTS](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/functions-subquery), возвращающие просто bool но это как правило бывает не часто.